# JSON.Stringify ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, reflection

I am trying to post data in JSON format to a .NET MVC Controller like this.

```
$.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: 'http://mvc.tester.local/Home/NameConverter',
         data: JSON.stringify({ convertermodel.InputName: obj.currentTarget.value }),
         contentType: 'application/json'
});
```

But Javascript complains about the `JSON.Stringify()` bit.
The `convertermodel.InputName` to be exact.

The thing is I actually need this JSON data name to be that way i.e. have the same name as a property in my model; in order to take advantage of reflection for automatic binding.

This is my model:

```
public class NamesViewModel
{
    public NameConverterModel convertermodel = new NameConverterModel();        
}
```

and the sub Class

```
public class NameConverterModel
{
    private string _inputName = "";
    public string InputName
    {
        get { return _inputName; }
        set { _inputName = value; }
    }    
}
```

How can I solve this please ?

I hope I am clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need your JSON to be of the structure like this:

```
{"convertermodel" : {
                      "InputName" : obj.currentTarget.value
                    }
}
```

Your JSON representation of your object needs to reflect the appropriate nesting that your object model that you're trying to model in the client-side requires.  So defining your JSON by nesting your hierarchy at one level won't work -- you need to create objects of objects like you did in your C# code.

Comment: Wow, why didn't I think of that ?
I haven't tested this, but I'm sure it is the right answer.
Testing now, thanks

Comment: I hope this helps.  If it does, don't forget to mark this as an answer.  It will help your accept percentage.

Comment: No problem - glad to be of help!